# (jquery) masked input plugin overwrites text when maxlength is reached

Tags: jquery, input

Let's say I have a input like this:

```
$('#phone').mask("?99999", { placeholder: "" });
```

If I type `'12345'`, then put the cursor between `3` and `4`, and press `1`, the text will be like:
`'12314'`

I'd like a behavior like `maxlength`, that prevents any additional character when the limit is reached, so the text would stay '12345' if `maxlength = 5`.

This is the plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: What is wrong with `maxlength`?

Comment: maxlength doesn't work with this plugin.

Comment: @FelipeVaz can you show how you include the plugin please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

First, use the solution found here [How do I keep existing values from shifting to the right when entering keypresses into a jQuery Masked Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561252/how-do-i-keep-existing-values-from-shifting-to-the-right-when-entering-keypresse) to avoid the mask plugin behaviour that shifts characters to the right on keypresses.

Then, set maxlength as attribute on the input

```
<input type="text" id="phone" maxlength="5">
```

This will limit the input length.

Comment: As the plugin overwrites the text, the maxlength is never exceeded.

Comment: Ah. I can reproduce your problem now (http://jsfiddle.net/C2FvX/1/ ) Is it really such a big problem?

Comment: Try this change to the mask plugin (and set noshift: true) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561252/how-do-i-keep-existing-values-from-shifting-to-the-right-when-entering-keypresse?rq=1 - Then, maxlength would work.

Answer (score 3):

Adding it as an attribute with jQuery worked for me:

`$('#phone').mask("?99999", { placeholder: "" }).attr('maxlength', 5);`

Answer (score 0):

put a MAXLEN on the input element.

Answer (score 0):

Understood what you're trying to achieve.

Assuming you have a textbox like this :

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

The jquery code for the input validation is :

```
$('#username').on('input', function() {

     var value = $('#username').val();

    if (value.length == '5') {
       $('#username').attr('readonly', true);


    }
});
```

I've done a jsfiddle for you. Try this :
http://jsfiddle.net/4Rxh7/1/

Comment: Sorry, but the mask plugin breaks it: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rxh7/2/ Also, it is not a very good solution that you could not edit the value...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="5">
```

javascript:

```
$('#username').on('keydown', function(event) {

    var txtBox = $('#username');
    if (txtBox.attr("maxlength") == txtBox.val().length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
$('#username').mask("?99999", { placeholder: "" });
```